# Exclude printers redirected by remote desktop connection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing, remote-desktop

I have a method that enumerates all locally installed printers using the LocalPrintServer class. when someone is using the application from a remote desktop connection, i want to fiter out the printer that are redirected by the remote desktop conntection.

```
 using (LocalPrintServer printServer = new LocalPrintServer())
            {
                var printQueuesOnLocalServer = printServer.GetPrintQueues(
                   new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });

                var terminalRedirectedPrintQueues = printQueuesOnLocalServer
                    .Except(printServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.TerminalServer }));

                // Filter out the printers that are redirected from a remote desktop connection
                // TODO: doesn't work, GetPrintQueues always returns all printers
                foreach (PrintQueue printer in printQueuesOnLocalServer.Where(
                    p => !terminalRedirectedPrintQueues.Select(t => t.FullName).Contains(p.FullName)))
                {
                    yield return printer.FullName;
                }
            }
```

Unfortunately, the Enumerable returned is always empty, because the two calls to GetPrintQueues return the same printer collection despite being called with different parameters. Is this a problem of the machine? Or is it that i just have misunderstood the way GetPrintQueues works?